# How to compare strings of dates that come from two different sources and dates are in different format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I have two dataframes which contain column Holidays - values are strings of dates (date ranges).
In one of them the format is following: `2018-01-01_2018-01-03,2018-04-17_2018-05-05,2019-03-20_2019-03_21`
In the second one: `01-JAN-18_03-JAN-18,17-APR-18_05-MAY-18,20-MAR-19_21-MAR-19`

How to compare if the dates match between two sources?

Comment: Parse them appropriately & compare the date values.

Comment: If you are going to work with dates, I suggest that you first split those dates in two different columns, hence it's pretty easy to transform those dates in datetime.datetime format and work with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split each string on `'_'` and cast the resulting list to `datetime`. Compare the datetime tuples you obtain from that row-wise:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'range0':['2018-01-01_2018-01-03','2018-04-17_2018-05-05','2019-03-20_2019-03-21', ''],
                   'range1':['01-JAN-18_03-JAN-18','17-APR-18_05-MAY-18','20-MAR-19_21-MAR-19', '']})

def equal_daterange(c0, c1, sep='_'):
    if c0 and c1: # make sure strings c0 and c1 are not empty
        r0 = pd.to_datetime(c0.split(sep))
        r1 = pd.to_datetime(c1.split(sep))
        return all(r0 == r1)
    return False # implicit else: strings c0 and/or c1 were empty

df['range_equal'] = df.apply(lambda x: equal_daterange(x['range0'], x['range1']), axis=1)
  
# df['range_equal']
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3    False
# Name: range_equal, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @Sebastian: not sure I can follow, so you have strings with multiple date ranges, and what exactly do you want to compare? that all ranges in two strings are equal? it would be great if you could edit your question by adding a [mre] (that would justify a re-open I guess...)

Comment: thank you for this solution! Could you please tell me how to amend the code so that once there is an empty string '' in both range0 and range1 it outputs True instead of False?

Comment: @Sebastian: you could check for that upfront, before trying to convert to datetime, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, got the basis of a solution for you.

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_match(s1,s2) -> bool:
    for a,b in zip(s1.split("_"),s2.split("_")):
        d1 = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d2 = datetime.strptime(b, "%d-%b-%y")
        if d1 != d2: return False
    return True

assert is_match("2018-01-01_2018-01-03","01-JAN-18_03-JAN-18") == True
assert is_match("2019-01-01_2018-01-03","01-JAN-18_03-JAN-18") == False
```

I want you to comment with if you understand this or if you need to ask any further questions. Good source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html